# How to check for drupal page routine, no form submit working

Tags: security

On my drupal website, I suddenly can't submit any form successfully. The page appears to reload but does not go anywhere, stays exactly where any form is.

Using drush uli, I can get in as admin but can't make any changes. The website is here: http://162.243.88.90

I hope someone knows a fix to this one or any tests I can run to track what could be causing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yea I tried a random login but redirect. Do you remember any specific changes you made and are there any permissions that could be set wrong that Would disabble admin making changes or anonymous logging in?

Comment: I don't remember making changes that'd stop users from logging in, no.